# Debian Linux: /usr/bin/nologin missing

Tags: linux, debian

I have set up a Debian Linux server, now I want to disable the shell so the user can't login and just connect via SFTP. But my `/usr/bin/nologin` is missing for some reason.
In which package is it located?

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Fnologin&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, `nologin` is located in `/usr/sbin`, not in `/usr/bin`. It is shipped with the package `login`:

```
$ whereis nologin
nologin: /usr/sbin/nologin /usr/share/man/man8/nologin.8.gz /usr/share/man/man5/nologin.5.gz
$ dpkg --search /usr/sbin/nologin
login: /usr/sbin/nologin
```

Answer (score 0):

I am more familiar with RedHat style Linux distributions than with Debian style. But in my experience, nologin is /usr/sbin/nologin and it is provided by a package named util-linux.

Answer (score 0):

It is located in `/usr/sbin` not `/usr/bin`.

Use find command to find files: `find / -name nologin`

The package is called "login" (`dpkg -S /usr/sbin/nologin`).

Alternatively you can also use `/bin/false`.

Comment: Wouldn't be `locate` much easier? Is there any difference/upside in using `find`?

Comment: Find is slower. It looks real time at the file system.
Locate does that once per day (usually around 3AM, when it is unlikely to bother the user).